# Hilbert-Schmidt integral operator with missing eigenfunctions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, hilbert-spaces, integral-operators

I'm having some issues with the spectral decomposition of the integral operator
\begin{equation}
    (Af)(x)=\int_0^1|x-y|f(y)dy,\text{ with $f\in L^2[0,1]$}.
\end{equation}
Since
\begin{equation}
    \int_0^1\int_0^1|x-y|^2\,dx\,dy<\infty \text{ and } |x-y|=|y-x|,
\end{equation}
this is a self-adjoint Hilbert-Schmidt integral operator. Therefore the spectral theorem for compact self-adjoint operators guarantees the existence of an orthonormal basis of $L^2[0,1]$ of eigenfunctions of $A$. Since $Af$ is Lipshitz, if $Af=\lambda f$ with $\lambda\ne0$, $f$ must be twice continuously differentiable, and satisfy the o.d.e.
\begin{align}
f''(x)=\frac{2}{\lambda}\,f(x).
\end{align}
It follows that the only eigenfunctions associated with a strictly negative eigenvalue are of the form $f(x)=\cos((2n+1)\pi x)$, with $n\ge0$ an integer (the associated eigenvalue is $\lambda=\frac{-2}{\pi^2(2n+1)^2}$.) There are, however, no eigenfunctions associated with a $\lambda>0$. Furthermore we are able to prove there are no eigenfunctions associated with $\lambda=0$. So, since $f(x)=1$ is orthogonal to the eigenfunctions $\cos((2n+1)\pi x)$, with $n\ge0$, these are an incomplete base for $L^2[0,1]$. (Treating $A$ as a convolution and using a Fourier series decomposition yields the same form of eigenfunctions.)

I have two issues: (1) finite approximations of this operator imply a (single) positive eigenvalue (with the largest modulus out of all eigenvalues)---although $A$ doesn't have positive eigenvalues; and finally (2) the finite approximations also imply eigenfunctions that do not correspond to any of the functions $\cos((2n+1)\pi x)$, with $n\ge0$.

Comment: Fixed, thanks. The boundary conditions can be obtained by splitting the domain of the integral operator to remove the absolute value and differentiating. They are $\lambda(f(0)+f(1))=\int_0^1f(y)dy$ and $f'(0)+f'(1)=0$

Comment: Form observation (1), it seems the most likely explanation is missing a positive eigenvalue which should be there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam This was my original thought as well, but assuming $\lambda>0$ leads to solutions of the form $f(x)=Ae^{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\lambda}}x}+Be^{-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\lambda}}x}$. Working the with boundary conditions (or just checking for solutions in maple) there are no nonzero solutions.

Comment: I don't obtain that for the boundary conditions. Please check. You have a positive compact operator, the Krein-Rutman Theorem applies (the infinite version of Perron-Frobenius). There is a positive eigenvalue, correponding to the only non sign changing eigensolution.

Comment: @username This is very helpful and the finite approximation does predict a non sign changing eigenfunction associated with the single positive eigenvalue. Which boundary conditions are you obtaining? Splitting the domain and differentiating I'm left with: $\int_0^xf(y)dy+\int_1^xf(y)dy=\lambda f'(x)$

Comment: Your first comment basically answers your question: with the correct boundary conditions, $\cos(2n+1)\pi x$ is actually not an eigenfunction, nor is $-2/((2n+1)\pi)^2$ an eigenvalue. The actual conditions are messier. So we can't tell very easily what space these span. In any event, there will also be a positive eigenvalue, with eigenfunction of the form $A\cosh kx + B\sinh kx$, $k^2=2/\lambda$. (More explicit conditions could be written down, but it doesn't look like one can solve it all the way through to the end.)

Comment: @ChristianRemling Why would $\cos((2n+1)\pi x)$ not be eigenfunctions? I believe they satisfy the boundary conditions I listed in my first comment. Are you getting different boundary conditions?

Comment: \begin{align*}
&(\int_0^x(x-y)f(y)dy+\int_x^1(y-x)f(y)dy)^\prime \\
=&\int_0^x f(y)dy +x(f(x)-f(0)) -xf(x)-\int_x^1f(y)dy \\&- x(f(1)-f(x))+f(1)-xf(x)\\
&= \int_0^x f(y)dy  -\int_x^1f(y)dy - x(f(1)+f(0)) +f(1) 
\end{align*}

Comment: @EvanGorman: Actually, they do. The antiperiodic eigenfunctions (that is $f(1)=-f(0)$, $f'(1)=-f'(0)$) that don't satisfy your bc's are the sine functions, but that too messes things up (the antiperiodic eigenfunctions would have spanned the whole space, being the eigenfunctions of a self-adjoint operator).

Comment: In other words, the cosine functions only span about half the space anyway (if that makes sense).

Comment: @ChristianRemling Yes exactly, that's why I'm wondering where the rest of the eigenfunctions can be found because this operator should guarantee a full basis.

Comment: @EvanGorman: I don't think anything is suspicious or unexpected here. My guess would be that the double antiperiodic ev's split into two simple ev's (that's another bunch of eigenfunctions, doubling the cosines), plus one eigenfunction with a positive eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured a positive eigenvalue. For $\lambda>0$, if $f(x) := \alpha\exp(\tau x)+ \exp(-\tau x)$ with $\alpha$ a constant and $\tau=\sqrt{2/\lambda}$ then $Af-\lambda f=0$ if and only if
$$\frac{e^{-\tau}-\alpha e^{\tau}-(\alpha-1)}{\tau}x+\frac{(-1-\tau) e^{-\tau}-\alpha(1-\tau)e^{\tau}-\alpha-1}{\tau^2}=0,\text{ for all }0\le x\le1.$$
To annihilate the linear term in x, you can solve for $\alpha$ in terms of $\tau$ to obtain
$$\alpha=\frac{1+e^{-\tau}}{1+e^{\tau}}.$$
Substituting this value on the other term gives
$$\frac{(-1-\tau) e^{-\tau}-\alpha(1-\tau)e^{\tau}-\alpha-1}{\tau^2}=\frac{(-\tau-2) e^{-\tau}-4+(\tau-2)e^{\tau}}{1+e^\tau},$$
which vanishes only when
$$e^\tau=\frac{\tau+2}{\tau-2},$$
and a plot suggests that this is possible at a unique value of $\tau\approx 2.4$.

Comment: @EvanGorman: There may be other positive eigenvalues. The one above corresponds to searching for one with an eigenfunction of the form $A e^{\tau}+B e^{-\tau x}$ with $B\ne0$.